# Outlook Add-in: Pinnable Taskpane does not refresh view In Outlook

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

we have implemented the Pinnable Taskpane by following the article below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane
This works well in Outlook and OWA both.

Issue: We have 4 Ribbon command button for our Outlook add-in in Read view. We activate the Add-In with one of the button, lets say button A. Once the add-in is activated it shows the functionality from button A. We then pin the taskpane and move around the different messages. while navigating through certain special messages, app view changes and shows the data from the message. This is expected behavior. Once this view is loaded, we can not reset to original view by clicking the button A again on the Ribbon. However if we click button B, it eventually opens up another Task pane instance on top of previously pinned one and navigates to functionality B. The only way it can be reset is to unpin and restart the add-in.

This does not happen in OWA and only specific to Outlook. I ran a test on Outlook 2016 build 9126.2282.

Could someone point out if this is a known issue?

Comment: Whether or not the taskpane reopens if the same button is clicked, is currently a difference between the two clients. I am not sure if this will change in the future. (or to which behavior we would change to). What is your scenario where you need the pane to refresh if the button is clicked again? (as opposed to losing context, and reloading the pane?)

Comment: Thanks. We would want to reset to original view when user clicks the same ribbon button again. As of today only way to reset the view in Outlook client is to unpin, close the app and restart.  Isn't this considered as a bug?

Comment: You can close the add-in without unpinning it. That's generally how people reload the apps. Why do you need to reload the add-in? You can't rely on your users to reload the add-in if that is part of your user scenario...

Comment: We would want to have the experience that once app is pinned, they just don't have to close the app to reset the view. Closing and restarting the app will  require pinning again. This works well in OWA but not in Outlook client.

Comment: In general we advise against designing Add-ins in ways that need a user to reload them. The ItemChanged event is a great way to receive a signal that your Add-in should "reset" itself for the new item your user has selected. Alternatively, if you have several views a user might wish to keep active while changing items, we recommend providing the user with navigation buttons for a better experience than clicking the Add-in again. Will this work instead for your scenario?

Comment: We do have navigation inside our app and also we do reset the view. I was curious to know if Ribbon issue is a known issue or it's by design for Outlook (not OWA). Thanks for your response though!